# spacemacs: keep track locations of smart search

Tags: helm, spacemacs

I have custom visit history ring which is independant of search seach engine used. I would like spacemacs smart search filled my ring as well.

Details:

```
1. I'm in some buffer under location1.
2. I've pressed "SPC *" or "SPC /" to do smart searching.
   a. during this helm process I can temporary visit intermediate locations
      through TAB key press. Let's say I visited: location2 and location3.
   b. but I pressed enter for location4.
3. I end up in location4.
```

I want location1 and location4 be added to my history ring.

Do You have an idea, what functions do I need to advice or what hooks to use in order to achieve this?

There is helm-ag-pop-stack, that might be helpful, but on the other hand it handles ag search engine only, while spacemacs smart search mechanism uses other engines as well.

Global mark ring does not leave location1 either.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution.

It is enough to advice 'before' and 'after' following functions:

spacemacs/helm-project-smart-do-search ;; SPC /

spacemacs/helm-project-smart-do-search-region-or-symbol ;; SPC *

best regards

Comment: If this post answers your problem, please accept it so we can mark it as done.